# google Maps: $.goMap() with custom overlayMapType

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, overlay

First: I try to remake a Website called [regionalkarten.com](http://www.regionalkarten.com/g_map_wrapper.html)
It's a German publisher of Maps. This page uses the Google API v2 to show our custom maps.

My Job is to update the Page to API v3.
Now I found the jQuery GoMap Plugin and I try to use it, but it doesn't seem to support **custom maps**.

I tried to define a Overly with the custom Map

```
var ehsTypeBOptions =
{
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom)
    {
        var x = coord.x;
        var y = coord.y;
        return "http://regionalkarten.com/_map/ehs_village_maps/is_maps/z"+zoom+"/"+coord.y+"/"+coord.x+".png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
};
```

and load it into the map with:

```
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new google.maps.ImageMapType(ehsTypeBOptions));
```

That works fine without GoMap. So I tried:

```
$.goMap.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new google.maps.ImageMapType(ehsTypeBOptions));
```

and guess what, it didn't work :(

[GoMaps Webpage](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/examples.php) and Google aren't very helpful. Keep in mind that I have to load the custom map into an overlay. I need the real google maps behind the overlay because our maps are not gapless.
I hope you got some ideas or experience with GoMap.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.goMap` does not return the native `google.maps.Map`-instance, so you can't use the Maps-API-methods there.

The google.maps.Map-instance may be accessed via `$.goMap.map` .

**Beyond that:** I would suggest not to use this library, there haven't been any updates since 1 year, and this all can be done without any additional library.

**More important:** before you continue working with `ImageMapType`, this is not the right MapType for you, because it appears that the TileServer don't serve tiles for the complete world.

When the user pans or zooms so that a area is in viewport where no tile is available, this area would be shown as a gray space. You better use a [`Overlay MapType`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#OverlayMapTypes) and set the background-image of the overlays to the TileUrl(additionally you may use a condition that checks if a Tile is available at all to reduce unnecessary request to the tile-server)

Comment: I thought I could spare me some work with this plug. Thanks for the Tip with the Overlay. Lets see how i get this working.